# Can i make a server open html instead of downloading it? if i can how?

Tags: python-3.x

i got that server:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 80


class MyRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, directory=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=None, **kwargs)
        self.path = 'path.html'

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            pass
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET


Handler = MyRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(('', PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print('Serving at port', PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

but it downloads the html file.
can i make it open it as the website?
if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to HTTP spec you need to have the below header set.

The content to be loaded from the browser instead of download.

```
Content-Disposition: inline
```

python code for the server

```
send_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline')
```

[content to display browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: Thanks you helped a lot